# Swift generics wired syntax that actually works, but can it be written differently?

Tags: objective-c, swift

So I have this function :

```
override func sendRequest(_ pageIndex: Int) -> CSResponse<AnyObject> & CSListData {
    return server.loadUserArticles(pageIndex)
}
```

It works and calls objective c function

```
- (CSResponse <CSListData> *)loadUserArticles:(NSInteger)pageIndex;
```

I am looking to documentation and cannot find explanation, CSListData is objc protocol and I was trying to write something like this

```
override func sendRequest<T : AnyObject & CSListData >(_ pageIndex: Int) -> CSResponse<T> {
        return server.loadUserArticles(pageIndex)
}
```

But this sadly does not compile with error because I am assigning it to property in objective c with this syntax

```
@property(nonatomic) CSResponse <CSListData> *(^onLoadList)(NSInteger);
```

Error:

```
Error:(26, 43) cannot assign value of type '(Int) -> CSResponse<_>' to type '(Int) -> CSResponse<AnyObject> & CSListData'
```

What is totally un understandable is why is return type `<AnyObject> & CSListData` when it is actually `CSResponse<CSListData>`. Thanks.

Comment: Isn’t it simply that Swift has generics but Objective-C doesn’t?

Comment: @matt I understand that you maybe never seen generics in objective c but you see it there now, or no ? Are you joking or what...

Comment: No, it has a kind of “lightweight generic” but it is not really related to Swift generics. You seem to think they are the same thing.